# R concatenate columns with added notations

Tags: r, concatenation, tidyr, paste

I am trying to select several columns from a data frame and then output them to an excel file.  For the last column I want to concatenate several columns with notation added between.

```
data %>%
  select(Place = place, Time = time, Number = paste(number_2, "(", number_1, 
                                              ",", number_3, ")")) %>%
  openxlsx::write.xlsx(file = here("data"))
```

I am getting the error

```
object not found
```

If I include the dataframe

```
data %>%
  select(Place = place, Time = time, Number = paste(data$number_2, "(", data$number_1, 
                                              ",", data$number_3, ")")) %>%
  openxlsx::write.xlsx(file = here("data"))
```

I get the following error

> Can't subset to columns that don't exist

A sample of the data is

```
Place   Time    Number 2    Number 1    Number 3
R1  T1  .5  .4  .7
R2  T1  .2  .1  .3
R1  T2  .4  .3  .6
R2  T2  .3  .2  .4
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Please show part of your `data`.

Comment: Don't use `data$` within the `dplyr` verbs, at best it's redundant/unnecessary, often (e.g., with grouping or mid-pipe reshaping/changes) it is wrong-data if not an error.

Comment: OK I've added a sample of the data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are attempting to access columns named `number_2` etc., but these columns don’t exist in the sample data you’ve posted.

You need to use the correct column name: `` `Number 2` ``.

```
data %>%
  select(
    Place = place,
    Time = time,
    Number = paste(`Number 2`, "(", `Number 1`, ",", `Number 3`, ")")
  ) %>%
  openxlsx::write.xlsx(file = here("data"))
```

Note the [backticks (`` ` ``)](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Quotes.html), which are needed around [“non-syntactic” names](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/names-values.html#non-syntactic) in R code (in your case, because your column names contain spaces, which isn’t syntactically valid).